# How many objects can be stored or cached in Parse Local Data Storage?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have my application with Parse.com as a backend. To reduce performance issues I am reducing network calls rather I have enabled Local Datastore for Parse.

However I want to know how many objects are pinned in Local Data Store. Can I store whatever numbers of objects I want.

One more thing to unpin all objects from local datastore. I am going to write Service in Android which will run after one day clear local datastore.

I used ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground();

but it doesnt work please help.

Comment: Try posting what you've done, so I can help you !